# Genymotion emulator camera cannot save pictures

Tags: android, camera, save, emulation, genymotion

This is a problem I've had with both the Android Studio emulator and now also in Genymotion. I can set up the camera fine, either by connecting to webcam0 or an emulated virtual camera. But when I take a picture and tap the 'accept picture' check mark, nothing happens. The exact same app works fine when I test my code on a physical Android device. But now, two different emulators cannot save the pictures. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Which genymotion version are you using ?

Comment: I am using genymotion 2.4

Comment: I fixed my own problem. The directory I was using wasn't working and so it wouldn't let me save into it.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Emulator Make Sure you Create SD Card with some size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below step for getting dummy camera picture from genymotion.

1. Start genymotion
2. Click on web camera icon which is below GPS icon.
3. CAMERA dialog will open and enable switch OFF to ON.
4. Click PREVIEW and check any one option either FRONT or BACK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. An update to Genymotion plugin 1.0.7 solved it immediatley.